# Update firmware bug ubuntu LIVE

Tags: boot, dell, firmware, microcode

Upon booting from a CD or USB with an Ubuntu iso to reinstall everything, an error appears

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please update microcode to version: 0x52 (or later)
```

I have, as suggested, installed intel-microcodes and rebooted

```
sudo apt-get install intel-microcode

intel-microcode is already the newest version (3.20180425.1~ubuntu0.17.10.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
```

After rebooting, error still there...

What can I do?

Comment: Your iso image is which version?

Comment: Tried with 16.04 and 18.04

Comment: Hi, are you on live session with the usb? Can you make one more command `sudo apt-get upgrade intel-microcode`